# Using IrrKlang with Ogre

Tags: audio, ogre, ogre3d, irrklang

I'm trying to set up sound in my Ogre3D project. I have installed irrKlang 1.4.0 and added it's include and lib directories to my projects VC++ Include and Library directories, but I'm still getting a Linker error when I attempt to build. Any suggestions?

> (Error    4007    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) class irrklang::ISoundEngine * __cdecl
>   irrklang::createIrrKlangDevice(enum
>   irrklang::E_SOUND_OUTPUT_DRIVER,int,char const *,char const *)"
>   (_*imp*?createIrrKlangDevice@irrklang@@YAPAVISoundEngine@1@W4E_SOUND_OUTPUT_DRIVER@1@HPBD1@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: __thiscall
>   SoundManager::SoundManager(void)" (??0SoundManager@@QAE@XZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after looking at this for awhile it seems I was making two mistakes.

1. The lib directory for irrKlang is divided in two, so instead of adding (IRRKLANGDIRECTORY)\lib to my library directories, I should have been using (IRRKLANGDIRECTORY)\lib\Win32-visualStudio.
2. Including the lib directory wasn't sufficient, I also needed to specify the use of the irrklang library file at the top of my class (#pragma comment(lib, "irrklang.lib")).